# cref and external documents

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

I want two things: 1. to be able to use `\cref` across different files and 2. to display certain environments (just the theorems for example) from an external file.

What I mean by (2) is the following. Suppose I have theorems in a file called `external.tex`. Suppose I'm working in `main.tex`. I want all of the theorems from `external.tex` to be pasted into `main.tex` without having to rewrite them.

Here is my code for (1):

external.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,cleveref}
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}
\begin{document}
\begin{lem}\label{mylemma}
blah blah blah
\end{lem}
\end{document}
```

main.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{xr}
\externaldocument[ext:]{external}
\begin{document}
using \cref{ext:mylemma}
\end{document}
```

When I use `\ref{ext:mylemma}`, it works. It just displays the number 1. When I use `\cref{ext:mylemma}`, I get "?? 1". How do I fix this?

Comment: Welcome! I think your two questions are independent of each other and should be asked as two separate questions. Since you already have an answer to the first part of your question, I would suggest editing this question to remove the second part and ask the removed part as a new separate question again.

Answer (score 2):

`cleveref` in `main.tex` does not know what the label type `lem` is (as indicated by the warning: `` cref reference format for label type `lem' undefined ``). Therefore, add `\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}` to the preamble of `main.tex` to define it therein.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}
\usepackage{xr}
\externaldocument[ext:]{external}
\begin{document}
using \cref{ext:mylemma}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `cleveref` is one of the packages that should be loaded right at the end of the preamble

Answer (score 2):

Instead of repeating the definition of `newtheorem lemma` it's possible to make `cleveref` aware of `lem` using `\crefname` or `\Crefname`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xr}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\externaldocument[ext:]{external}
\crefname{lem}{lemma}{lemmata}
\Crefname{lem}{Lemma}{Lemmata}

\begin{document}
using \cref{ext:mylemma} or \Cref{ext:mylemma}
\end{document}
```